# Swift Package Manager - copy files build phase for a dynamic dependency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, libsodium

I'm working on an iOS application, and the core of it we are going to open source as a standalone Swift Package for other developers.

The Swift Package depends on Sodium (https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium). There is an issue with this library when using SPM, that during archive (and sometimes during compile locally in Xcode) that it will fail to find the embedded CLibrary, making it impossible to release to the app store if using this package, or having it embedded in your own. (This is recorded as a bug in SPM / Xcode but will take sometime to fix)

Someone made a Fork that solves some of the problems [here](https://github.com/junelife/swift-sodium/tree/spm). They solved the issue by splitting the Clibrary out as a separate .xcframework hosted somewhere else. Then making a new Package.swift that imports it as an external dependency. This updated Sodium Package has been set to type dynamic.

Including this in my Swift package, and then including my package in my iOS application ... it builds fine, runs in Xcode fine, runs on simulators fine, throws no errors when exporting or upload to TestFlight.

However after downloading from TestFlight, I get this error saying the Sodium framework can't be found

```
Termination Description: DYLD, dyld: Using shared cache: <hash> | dependent dylib `@rpath/Sodium.framework/Sodium` not found for <path-to-ipa>/<appname> tried but didn't find <path-to-sodium>
```

Using other dependency management tools, the solution is usually to add a "Copy Files Build Phase" to the iOS application's xcode project and add the framework. If I try to do this in my Xcode project, I can't find the Sodium framework, and I can't find a way to tell SPM to copy the framework inside the `Package.swift`.

How do I update my Package.swift so that it copies this framework for any app that uses it?

If thats not possible, how do I copy it inside the Xcode project? Its not visible in the dropdown

Currently my Package.swift looks like this:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "<package-name>",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14)],
    products: [
        .library(name: "<package-name>", targets: ["<package-name>"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt.git", from: "5.2.1"),
        .package(name: "Sodium", url: "https://github.com/junelife/swift-sodium.git", .branch("spm"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "<package-name>",
            dependencies: [
                "Sodium",
                "BigInt",
            ]
        ),
        
        .testTarget(
            name: "<package-name>Tests",
            dependencies: ["<package-name>"]
        ),
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for now:

If I import the dynamic package into the iOS app as well, I get the option to "Embed and sign" next to the Sodium framework under `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content` under the general tab of the target. Which forces it into the bundle.

Note:
I attempted to make my Package Dynamic, to see if including it would embed everything automatically and avoid having to give users instructions to users to embed it separately. But it didn't work. It only embedded my package and not the dynamic dependency.

If anyone has a way to modify a Package.swift to force it to embed dynamic dependencies ... or knows how to clean up this mess entirely. Please comment

Comment: Hi @simon-mcloughlin,
did you find how to modify Package.swift?

Comment: @Sheikh sorry no i'm still using this workaround. The bug thats stopping me using the static version of sodium, has been called out as a known issue for Xcode 13. I'm hoping that will be fixed/released soon and I will be able to side step this issue entirely. SPM + dynamic packages is horribly documented online, I gave up searching for the answer, since Xcode 13 might fix my specific issue

Comment: Ok, got you. 
I hope Xcode 13 will bring fixes for this. Thanks, Simon!